# Android/Eclipse: How to change project name on import?

Tags: android, eclipse

This is going on my nerves for so long now... I want to **import an existing android project into my workspace**, but sometimes there is **already an existing project with the same name** (best example: `MainActivity`, which is the most common name for example projects in tutorials)

[image]

So I cannot import the new project into the workspace. Usually, I have to delete the `MainActivity project A`, before I can import `project B` using the same project name. Or (**before** import) I have to rename/modify the `MainActivity` and the `Manifest.xml` from `project B`.

I know the `New Project Name` field is editable, but if I change the project name i still cannot import the project into the workspace.

Is there any other workaround???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your existing project (f.e. `MainActivity2`)

Right click on the project --> Refactor --> Rename .

Import the project (in your case `MainActivity`)

Comment: the problem occurs BEFORE importing the projects into eclipse, so I cannot rename it

Comment: ok then rename the already imported projects , then import what you want

Comment: Actually renaming the existing project is not an answer, if it was then why ask the question in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

Open the project folder and edit the ".project" file. Just edit the name there.

Comment: not every project containing the `.project` file. check this one for example http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Create a new file in that folder, called .project, and the file should contain something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
 <name>title</name>
</projectDescription>
`  After that you can import the project normally

Answer (score 3):

Change the project name in the field "New Project Name" by double click on name you will get editbox type the project name you want for project as shown in screen you will able to import the same project with different name.

[image]

Comment: This worked! Far saner than some other suggested solutions.

Comment: it was for older versions @olenz